# Problema al mostrar un tab-pane

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando los tab de bootstrap 4 pero tengo un problema: cuando el doy click a un item del menu me muestra el contenido que pertenece a ese item, si le doy click a otro item, me deberia de ocultar el que mostré antes y mostrar al que le di clic,
si me devuelvo al item que primero le di click me muestra los 2 contenidos, la idea es que me muestre al que le di click y no me muestre varios...

**PD: Tambien necesito que cuando el de click el icono de font-awesome cambie la clase a fa-angle-up y viceversa**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // TOGGLE SCRIPT

  $(".nav-link").click(function() {
    var t = $(this).attr("href");

    $(t).toggleClass('active');


  }); // END TOGGLE

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Card</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container py-5">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="descripcion-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active" href="#descripcion" role="tab" aria-controls="descripcion" aria-selected="true">
      Descripción
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="gestion-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#gestion" role="tab" aria-controls="gestion" aria-selected="false">
      Gestión online
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="caracteristicas-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#caracteristicas" role="tab" aria-controls="caracteristicas" aria-selected="false">
      Características
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="requisitos-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#requisitos" role="tab" aria-controls="requisitos" aria-selected="false">
      Requisitos
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tabItems">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="descripcion" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="descripcion-tab">
        <h1>Descripción</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="gestion" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="gestion-tab">
        <h1>Gestión Online</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="caracteristicas" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="caracteristicas-tab">
        <h1>Características</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="requisitos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="requisitos-tab">
        <h1>Requisitos</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay que crear una función para quitar la clase activa a todos los contenedores y restablecer los íconos con la clase `down`. Luego, en la función que ya tienes, activar el contenedor y el ícono del enlace.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // TOGGLE SCRIPT
  $(".nav-link").click(function() {
    // Eliminar clase activa a todos los elementos
    removeActive();
    // Activar solo el que se hizo click
    var t = $(this).attr("href");
    $(t).addClass('active');
    // Obtener ícono y cambiar clase
    var i = $(this).children()[0];
    $(i).attr('class', 'fa fa-angle-up');
  }); // END TOGGLE
});

function removeActive() {
   // Recorrer todos los elementos
   $('.nav-link').each(function() {
       // Quitar clase activa a cada uno
       var t = $(this).attr("href");
       $(t).removeClass('active');
       // Obtener ícono y restablecer clase
       var i = $(this).children()[0];
       $(i).attr('class', 'fa fa-angle-down');
   });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Card</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container py-5">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="descripcion-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active" href="#descripcion" role="tab" aria-controls="descripcion" aria-selected="true">
      Descripción
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="gestion-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#gestion" role="tab" aria-controls="gestion" aria-selected="false">
      Gestión online
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="caracteristicas-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#caracteristicas" role="tab" aria-controls="caracteristicas" aria-selected="false">
      Características
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="requisitos-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#requisitos" role="tab" aria-controls="requisitos" aria-selected="false">
      Requisitos
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tabItems">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="descripcion" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="descripcion-tab">
        <h1>Descripción</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="gestion" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="gestion-tab">
        <h1>Gestión Online</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="caracteristicas" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="caracteristicas-tab">
        <h1>Características</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="requisitos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="requisitos-tab">
        <h1>Requisitos</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

La función que tenías creada estaba ocasionando que el comportamiento de los *tabs* fuese erróneo. Eliminando dicha función conseguirías que no te ocurra el problema de varias *tabs* abiertos a la vez.

Luego corregí unas cuanta cosas. Si inicialmente el tab **Descripción** está activo, también debería aparecer su contenido y tener el icono `.fa-angle-up` en vez de `.fa-angle-down`.

Una vez establecido un punto de partida correcto, lo que hice fue crear una función `click` que al pulsar en un `.nav-item` le quite a todos el icono de abierto para sustituirlo por el de cerrado menos al que se le ha hecho `click`, que se le hace la operación inversa.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.nav-item').click(function () {
    //Le quitamos la clase fa-angle-up a todos los <i> y les añadimos la clase fa-angle-down
    $('.fa').removeClass('fa-angle-up').addClass('fa-angle-down');
    // Le quitamos la clase fa-angle-down al <i> seleccionado y le añadimos la clase fa-angle-up
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up');;
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Card</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container py-5">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="descripcion-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active" href="#descripcion" role="tab" aria-controls="descripcion" aria-selected="true">
      Descripción
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="gestion-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#gestion" role="tab" aria-controls="gestion" aria-selected="false">
      Gestión online
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="caracteristicas-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#caracteristicas" role="tab" aria-controls="caracteristicas" aria-selected="false">
      Características
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="requisitos-tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#requisitos" role="tab" aria-controls="requisitos" aria-selected="false">
      Requisitos
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tabItems">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="descripcion" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="descripcion-tab">
        <h1>Descripción</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="gestion" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="gestion-tab">
        <h1>Gestión Online</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="caracteristicas" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="caracteristicas-tab">
        <h1>Características</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="requisitos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="requisitos-tab">
        <h1>Requisitos</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```